# Why does my laptop get too hot when the AC power is plugged in?

Tags: power-management

im using natty and when my computer is on AC power it gets very hot (no independent graphic card). But when im with only battery, the machine itself is quite cool.

I've just tried sometime on the power management but seems can't tune my computer cooler when with ac power, as i does on battery.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One of the known bugs of Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal is the power consumption increase and resulting heat. It is caused by the Linux Kernel 2.6.28. Upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot when it gets released should solve the problem.

Source:

> 10-30% increase in power consumption.
>   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/TechnicalOverview#Linux_kernel

Comment: but when using battery it's not so hot...